# Access Javascript Json Array in Object

Tags: arrays, json

How to access the first entry in a Json response like this:

```
[{"id":"3062","status":"1"}]
```

I tought it would be:
    json[0]["id"]

Comment: In what language? Yes, that would work in JavaScript (or TypeScript, or CoffeeScript), to access the `id` property of the object in the array at position 0 once you've parsed the JSON (so it's not JSON anymore, it's an array with an object in it). JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Only if you have it assigned to a var `json` which you don’t in your example. So `var json = [{blah: ‘yada’}]` could be accessed by `json[0].blah` or `json[0][blah]`. But an array just floating in space is just that.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention. Its coming from php json_encode and I try to access it with js. Unfortunately nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json_response = '[{"id":"3062","status":"1"}]';
var arr = JSON.parse(json_response);
arr[0]["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this script. It returns the value of `id` is **3062**

```js
var json_response = '[{"id":"3062","status":"1"}]';
var arr = JSON.parse(json_response);
document.write(arr[0].id);
```